# Reading entries from whitespace-separated lines in java

Tags: java, whitespace

I'm trying to read entries/lines of whitespace-separated columns in java.

Example:

```
Header (without quotes):
"  A B  C   DDD EE         FFFFFFF  GG  "
```

Lines (without quotes):

```
"     9 $   123456     foobar      3.0   foo, bar      "<br>
"     4 %      654       barf      1.0   foobar, foobar"
```

mapping for line 1:

```
A: 9
B: $
C: 123456
DDD: foobar
EE: 3.0
FFFFFFF: 
GG: foo, bar
```

Problem is that the width of each column can differ and that the header columns are not in the same horizontal level like the lines with the values.

Things that are known:

- there is exactly one whitespace between the columns as a separator
- fillcharacter is/are a/many whitespace(s)

I tried to count the whitespaces but I had problems, when there are two empty columns. Even with pattern matching or regular expressions I couldn't find a solution. Split(" ") doesn't work because there might be many epmty columns.

Any hint/help would be great.

Comment: Specifying the language you are using would help people help you. A code sample and example of wanted output would also help.

Comment: sorry, did forget to mention it. I have to use java.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? You can use a regex in PHP to split the white spaces:

```
$string = ' A B C DDD EE FFFFFFF  GG ';
$arr = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $string);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you but I have to use java. Parsing the header isn't the problem. I have some trouble parsing the line with the data...